# solo dato type string en python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Amigos Pythonistas, como novato y tratando de aprender sobre programacion en python, quisiera la ayuda sobre como lograr obtener solamente datos string(nombre) en una funcion, y que no me permita continuar si no digito texto. mi codigo es:

```
class Nomina:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre_empleado = ""

    def ObtenerDatos (self):
        if(type(self.nombre_empleado == str)):
            self.nombre_empleado = str(input("EL NOMBRE DEL EMPLEADO ES : "))
        else:
            print("pasa")


    def mostrarDatos (self):
        print("-----------------------------------------")
        print("LOS DATOS PARA SU LIQUIDACION SON :")
        print("-----------------------------------------")
        print("Nombre del Empleado :", self.nombre_empleado)
```

y este el resultado:

> ```
> EL NOMBRE DEL EMPLEADO ES : 445    
> -----------------------------------------    
> LOS DATOS PARA SU LIQUIDACION SON :    
> -----------------------------------------    
> >Nombre del Empleado : 445    
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

y ha pesar de digitar un dato tipo inetgrer o entero lo recibe y continua la ejecución. ¿Cómo hago para que solo permita digitar tipo texto y no continue si no digito el string?.

Comment: Cuando llamas a input, lo que obtienes es un `str` ... Y sobre eso, realizas otra conversión al hacer `str(input(...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Python 3.x `input` **retorna siempre una cadena.** No es necesario que hagas casting a `str`, ya lo es. Si deseas que el `input` no contenga caracteres numéricos deberás validar la cadena y actuar en consecuencia (lanzando una excepción o pidiendo de nuevo los datos). Dependiendo de lo que quieras puedes usar [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha), [`str.isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) o expresiones regulares para cosas más complejas.

```
class Nomina:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre_empleado = ""

    def obtenerDatos (self):
        nombre = input("EL NOMBRE DEL EMPLEADO ES : ")
        if nombre.isalpha():
            self.nombre_empleado = nombre
        else:
            print("pasa")


    def mostrarDatos (self):
        print("-----------------------------------------")
        print("LOS DATOS PARA SU LIQUIDACION SON :")
        print("-----------------------------------------")
        print("Nombre del Empleado :", self.nombre_empleado)
```

En este caso con `isalpha` cualquier texto ingresado que contenga un carácter que no esté entre A-Z y a-z incluido el espacio será invalido. Con `isnumeric` textos como 'Ramon1' son válidos pero no '123' no lo sería.

Generalmente la opción más flexible son las expresiones regulares, por ejemplo, para validar nombres del tipo 'Antonio Jesús Cañamero' necesitaras incluir los acentos, la ñ y los espacios en la validación:

```
import re

class Nomina:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre_empleado = ""

    def obtenerDatos (self):
        nombre = input("EL NOMBRE DEL EMPLEADO ES : ")
        if re.match("^[A-Za-z áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ]*$", nombre):
            self.nombre_empleado = nombre
        else:
            print("pasa")


    def mostrarDatos (self):
        print("-----------------------------------------")
        print("LOS DATOS PARA SU LIQUIDACION SON :")
        print("-----------------------------------------")
        print("Nombre del Empleado :", self.nombre_empleado)

a = Nomina()
a.obtenerDatos()
```

Puedes crear tu expresión a medida para que acepte o no otras cosas como `_`, `-`, `@`, `.`, `,` etc.

**Edición:**

Si deseas que pida el nombre hasta que sea válido debes usar un ciclo infinito para que pida el `input` hasta que este sea validado:

```
import re

class Nomina:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre_empleado = ""

    def obtenerDatos (self): 
        while not self.nombre_empleado:
            nombre = input("EL NOMBRE DEL EMPLEADO ES : ")
            if re.match("^[A-Za-z áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ]*$", nombre):
                self.nombre_empleado = nombre
            else:
                print("NOMBRE INVÁLIDO")


    def mostrarDatos (self):
        print("-----------------------------------------")
        print("LOS DATOS PARA SU LIQUIDACION SON :")
        print("-----------------------------------------")
        print("Nombre del Empleado :", self.nombre_empleado)

a = Nomina()
a.obtenerDatos()
```

Comment: la primera opcion con isalpha()  me genera error al ejecutar y lograr obtener los datos.

Comment: @Jsierra2017 ambos códigos estan testeados en Python 3 y ninguno da genera ningún error. ¿Estas usando Python 3 como pones en la etiqueta de tu pregunta o usas python 2.x ? ¿Que error te da? ¿Es el mismo código exactamente que uso en el ejemplo?

Comment: la segunda propuesta si ejcuta el codigo y se logra obtener datos, cuan digito numeros inprime "pasa".

Comment: pero al agregar la funcion mostrar datos, si digito numero continua el proceso, y muestra resultado vacio, L NOMBRE DEL EMPLEADO ES : 454566
pasa
-----------------------------------------
LOS DATOS PARA SU LIQUIDACION SON :
-----------------------------------------
Nombre del Empleado :

Comment: y la idea es que no me permita continuar hasta que no digite lo pedido,

Comment: estoy ejecutando el codigo exactamente, como me lo proponen en pycharm

Comment: en python 3.5.2

Comment: @Jsierra2017 porque solo validas los datos y si son incorrectos imprimes 'pasa', el atributo nombre no cambia en este caso. Usa un ciclo while infinito en tu función `obtenerDatos` para que pida los datos hasta que sean correctos. Espera un momento y lo edito.

Comment: por que recuerda que debo ejecutar dos funciones, obtenerdatos y mostrardatos

Comment: @Jsierra2017 mira la edición al final de la respuesta, de esa forma estará pidiendo el nombre hasta que se ingrese algo válido. La idea es la misma para cualquier variable que quieras validar- Saludos.

Comment: excelente hermano, soluciona, la solicitud de ingresar texto valido. muy buenos tus aportes gracias.

Comment: tengo una duda (import re), a que funcion corresponde.

Comment: @Jsierra2017 `import re` importa el módulo [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) de la biblioteca estándar y es el que permite usar las expresiones regulares (se importa para poder usar la función `re.math()`). Recuerda marcar como [aceptadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) aquellas preguntas que te sean útiles y resulvan tu problema. Saludos.

Comment: ok gracias, ya le di acepatada

Answer (score 0):

La mejor opcion seria hacer un `for` dividiendo cada palabra con espacio para validar que cada parte del nombre si es un texto, asi si admite cualquier carácter como tilde y ñ, etc.

```
def obtenerDatos ():

    while True:
        nombre = input("Digite su nombre: ")
          
        lista_nombre = []

        nombre_separado = nombre.split(" ")

        for i in range(0, len(nombre_separado)):
            if nombre_separado[i].isalpha() == True:
                lista_nombre.append(nombre_separado[i])
        
        s = "".join(nombre_separado)
        
        if s.isalpha() == False:
            print("El nombre no es válido, digite su nombre real")
            print()
        
        if s.isalpha() == True:
            print()
            nombre = nombre.title()
            nombre = (f"Su nombre es: {nombre}")
            print(nombre)
            break
obtenerDatos()
```

También se usa un `while True` en caso de que haya algun número para repetir el momento donde se escribe el nombre. Saludos...

Comment: La edité a mi modo ya que no me convencia el otro estilo pero aun asi solo seria implementar el texto en el condicional `if s.isalpha() == True:`